# error with my code #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, android-studio, dart

There is my problem: I'm using the [share package][1] from pub.dev, and when I am trying to build my app, I got the following error:

````
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users//Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
    /Users//Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mac users:
In your flutter project, try running `flutter pub get` on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To fix error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
you need to remove or not use

`firebase_admob`

use

`native_admob_flutter`

OR

`admob_flutter`

and you get this error when you use firebase
and if you use like this code in podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```